# Using imputed datasets from library mice() to fit a multi-level model in R

Tags: r, missing-data, lme4, imputation, r-mice

I'm new to package `mice` in R. But I'm trying to impute 5 datasets from `popmis` and then fit an `lmer()` model `with()` each and finally `pool()` across them.

I think the `pool()` function in `mice()` doesn't work with the `lmer()` call from `lme4` package, right?

If that is the case, is there a way to write a custom-made function that acts like `pool()` for my case below?

```
library(mice)
library(lme4)

imp <- mice(popmis, m = 5) # `popmis` is a dataset from `mice`

fit <- with(imp, lme4::lmer(popular ~ sex + (1|school))) # works fine.

pool(fit) # BUT this one fails, should I loop here?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the solution for you. It is as simple as `install.packages("broom.mixed")` and then `library(broom.mixed)`.`broom.mixed` package is providing the proper `glance` method

```r
# install.packages("broom.mixed")
library(mice)
library(lme4)
library(broom.mixed)
imp <- mice(popmis, m = 5) # `popmis` is a dataset from `mice`

fit <- with(data = imp, exp = lme4::lmer(popular ~ sex + (1|school)))

pool(fit)
```

Results:

```r
> pool(fit)
Class: mipo    m = 5 
         term m  estimate        ubar            b           t dfcom       df        riv     lambda        fmi
1 (Intercept) 5 4.9122016 0.007589694 0.0003823641 0.008048531  1996 743.8691 0.06045526 0.05700878 0.05953397
2         sex 5 0.8378947 0.001187606 0.0002937859 0.001540149  1996  72.7305 0.29685175 0.22890184 0.24926611
```

[Ben Bolker is the author of broom.mixed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/190277/ben-bolker)

Comment: But `ubar` which relates to random-effects in your solution should ONLY show for `(intercept)` NOT for `sex` (as the model only has a random effect for `intercept`), what is going on here?

Comment: @BenBolker is the author of broom.mixed. For me it looks to be ok though I am not a specialist in mixed models.